# Rails selenium visit command firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, firefox, capybara, minitest

I am trying to run selenium  with capybara and minitest on ubuntu with firefox 50.1 but it won't visit any url. I just get firefox open but empty, but sometimes I get error 1:

testfile:

```
require "test_helper" 

feature "dashboard" do 

  scenario "test" , :js=>true do
    Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
    visit("http://www.google.com/")

    visit root_url
    end
end
```

gemfile:

```
 group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.53', '>= 2.53.4'
  gem 'minitest-reporters' 
  gem "minitest-rails-capybara"
```

error1:

> test_0001_test                                                 ERROR
>   (65.56s) Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unable to obtain stable
>   firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)
>               test/features/instance_dashboard_test.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in '

I am missing some configuration or something? I can't visit any url, and the test just doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having similar issues, and got by for a while by downgrading Firefox to the ESR version (as [acikojevic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7371353/acikojevic) mentioned) but in the end I found it easier to switch from Firefox to Chrome until geckodriver matures.

To do this, add the following to your `spec_helper.rb`:

```
# Use Chrome instead of Firefox until geckodriver matures
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
end
```

Comment: It worked, by the way, I had to install chromedriver and add it to path. I follow this link https://developers.supportbee.com/blog/setting-up-cucumber-to-run-with-Chrome-on-Linux/ but I used your configuration on my test_helper.rb

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which FF versions are supported on selenium 2.53, consider downgrading your FF version (aim for something like v46-v47) or upgrading selenium version (which would be better, but then you need additional geckodriver setup).
See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The best combination I found for myself is using *FF45 ESR + Selenium WebDriver 2.53.4*. Hopefully I tried also with *FF54 + Selenium 3.4.3* but you will need an installation of GeckoDriver as Firefox decided not to implement any native extensions of Selenium3+ for now.